# when i am installing caffe in my ubuntu 16.04 ,i have issue with openCV

Tags: python, linux, opencv, caffe

I was trying to install caffe in linux machine,and while i am trying to do  make build ,i am getting an issue with openCV. I am getting the following error

```
/usr/bin/ld:cannot find -lopencv_imgcodecs
/usr/bin/ld:cannot find -lopencv_videoio
collect2:error:ld returned 1 exit status.
```

can anyone help me in resolve this issue?

Comment: `imgcodecs` and `videoio` are both OpenCV modules that seem to be missing. Have you correctly installed OpenCV on your machine?

Answer (score 1):

This usually happens when you have either forgotten to uncomment line number 21(in my case) when you have opencv3 or if you have not checked the version properly.If opencv>=3.0 then in the makefile on line 181(in my case) add libraries like

```
LIBRARIES += glog gflags protobuf leveldb snappy \
  lmdb boost_system hdf5_hl hdf5 \
  opencv_core opencv_highgui opencv_imgproc opencv_imgcodecs
```

And also make sure to rebuild.